# Java - setting object with product and price into an array

Tags: java, swing

I am doing a Java project where I want to ask the user 3 times what the product is and then the price for this product, It is not said how this should be done so I figured a good way is to make an array with a length of 3, where each array element is an object with product and price, This is what I have done so far but do not know how to set the object keys `prod` and `price`

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class prices {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] objects = new String[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        objects[i].prod = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("product?"); 
        objects[i].price = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("price?"); 
    }
}
```

How can I make this work so i have an object in each element of the array? or something similar so that this can work 
Your help is much appreciated

Comment: Where are you storing your product and price?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you really should read your books if you want to take a programming class, I think this may be generic enough that it deserves an answer.
Getters and setters are left as an exercise for the reader.

You create a product class with the properties

```
public class Product
{
  public float price;
  public String name;
}

public class prices {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Product[] products = new Product[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        products[i].name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("product?"); 
        products[i].price = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("price?"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I am just starting high school java and was expected to make a new variable for each new product and a new variable for each new price, but because I previously self studied javascript I though I could try it a better quicker way here in Java. Thank you for showing me how ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a `Item` class that has the `prod` and `price` properties, and then create an array of them.

Note I am not giving you a full example as this should point you in the right direction.  You will need to add Getters/Setters for the class as well as any other methods you may need.

```
public class Item{
    private String prod;
    private float price;
}
```

And then your main class would change similar to this:

```
    Item[] objects = new Item[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        objects[i].setProd(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("product?")); 
        objects[i].setPrice(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("price?")); 
    }
```